# String based data encoding: Base64 vs Base64url

Tags: url, base64, base64url

What is the difference between Base64 and Base64url that I see in things like JSON web tokens?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Both Base64 and Base64url are ways to encode binary data in string form. You can read about the theory of base64 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The problem with Base64 is that it contains the characters `+`, `/`, and `=`, which have a reserved meaning in some filesystem names and URLs. So base64url solves this by replacing `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`. The trailing padding character `=` can be eliminated when not needed, but in a URL it would instead most likely be `%` URL encoded. Then the encoded data can be included in a URL without problems.

Here is a chart of the differences:

```
Index  Base64  Base64Url

0      A       A 
1      B       B 
2      C       C 
3      D       D 
4      E       E 
5      F       F 
6      G       G 
7      H       H 
8      I       I 
9      J       J 
10     K       K 
11     L       L 
12     M       M 
13     N       N 
14     O       O 
15     P       P 
16     Q       Q 
17     R       R 
18     S       S 
19     T       T 
20     U       U 
21     V       V 
22     W       W 
23     X       X 
24     Y       Y 
25     Z       Z 
26     a       a 
27     b       b 
28     c       c 
29     d       d 
30     e       e 
31     f       f 
32     g       g 
33     h       h 
34     i       i 
35     j       j 
36     k       k 
37     l       l 
38     m       m 
39     n       n 
40     o       o 
41     p       p 
42     q       q 
43     r       r 
44     s       s 
45     t       t 
46     u       u 
47     v       v 
48     w       w
49     x       x
50     y       y
51     z       z
52     0       0
53     1       1
54     2       2
55     3       3
56     4       4
57     5       5
58     6       6
59     7       7
60     8       8
61     9       9
62     +       -
63     /       _
       
       =       (optional)
```

Below I will quote the definitions from the standards.

#### [RCF 4648 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4)

> **4.  Base 64 Encoding**
>
> The following description of base 64 is derived from [3](https://brockallen.com/2014/10/17/base64url-encoding/), [4], [5],
> and [6].  This encoding may be referred to as "base64".
>
> The Base 64 encoding is designed to represent arbitrary sequences
> of    octets in a form that allows the use of both upper- and
> lowercase    letters but that need not be human readable.
>
> A 65-character subset of US-ASCII is used, enabling 6 bits to be
> represented per printable character.  (The extra 65th character, "=",
> is used to signify a special processing function.)
>
> The encoding process represents 24-bit groups of input bits as
> output    strings of 4 encoded characters.  Proceeding from left to
> right, a    24-bit input group is formed by concatenating 3 8-bit
> input groups.    These 24 bits are then treated as 4 concatenated
> 6-bit groups, each    of which is translated into a single character
> in the base 64    alphabet.
>
> Each 6-bit group is used as an index into an array of 64 printable
> characters.  The character referenced by the index is placed in the
> output string.
>
> ```
>                   Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet
>
>  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
>      0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
>      1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
>      2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
>      3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
>      4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
>      5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
>      6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
>      7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
>      8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
>      9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
>     10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
>     11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
>     12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
>     13 N            30 e            47 v
>     14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
>     15 P            32 g            49 x
>     16 Q            33 h            50 y
> ```
>
> Special processing is performed if fewer than 24 bits are available
> at the end of the data being encoded.  A full encoding quantum is
> always completed at the end of a quantity.  When fewer than 24 input
> bits are available in an input group, bits with value zero are added
> (on the right) to form an integral number of 6-bit groups.  Padding
> at the end of the data is performed using the '=' character.  Since
> all base 64 input is an integral number of octets, only the following
> cases can arise:
>
> (1) The final quantum of encoding input is an integral multiple of
> 24
> bits; here, the final unit of encoded output will be an integral
> multiple of 4 characters with no "=" padding.
>
> (2) The final quantum of encoding input is exactly 8 bits; here,
> the
> final unit of encoded output will be two characters followed by
> two "=" padding characters.
>
> (3) The final quantum of encoding input is exactly 16 bits; here,
> the
> final unit of encoded output will be three characters followed by
> one "=" padding character.
>
> **5.  Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet**
>
> The Base 64 encoding with an URL and filename safe alphabet has
> been    used in [12].
>
> An alternative alphabet has been suggested that would use "~" as
> the    63rd character.  Since the "~" character has special meaning in
> some    file system environments, the encoding described in this
> section is    recommended instead.  The remaining unreserved URI
> character is ".",    but some file system environments do not permit
> multiple "." in a    filename, thus making the "." character
> unattractive as well.
>
> The pad character "=" is typically percent-encoded when used in an
> URI [9], but if the data length is known implicitly, this can be
> avoided by skipping the padding; see section 3.2.
>
> This encoding may be referred to as "base64url".  This encoding
> should not be regarded as the same as the "base64" encoding and
> should not be referred to as only "base64".  Unless clarified
> otherwise, "base64" refers to the base 64 in the previous section.
>
> This encoding is technically identical to the previous one, except
> for the 62:nd and 63:rd alphabet character, as indicated in Table 2.
>
> ```
>      Table 2: The "URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet
>
>  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
>      0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
>      1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
>      2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
>      3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
>      4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
>      5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
>      6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
>      7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
>      8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
>      9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
>     10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
>     11 L            28 c            45 t            62 - (minus)
>     12 M            29 d            46 u            63 _
>     13 N            30 e            47 v           (underline)
>     14 O            31 f            48 w
>     15 P            32 g            49 x
>     16 Q            33 h            50 y         (pad) =
> ```

Comment: I'm probably missing somethings here. But 1. about "Here is a chart of the differences" <— everything is identical except for the `+` and `/`. right? 2. if `-` is masking `+` then how do you differentiate between `-` itself vs `-` when it's masking `+`?

Comment: @Honey, One: That's correct, Base64 and Base64url are only different in positions 62 and 63. Two: I wouldn't really say that `-` is masking `+`. It is just a different ASCII symbol that is being used to represent 62. If you want to actually represent the `-` character then it would be encoded as `LQ==`. See [this](https://www.base64encode.org/).

Comment: @Suragch - in terms of what's most commonly found out in the field, it makes sense to me that `base64url` is much more common than `base64`. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag, That seems right to me, too, but I'm not an expert in this area.

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but in case it helps anyone, if you are using .NET, you can encode/decode to/from Base64Url via the System.IdentityModel.Base64Url class provided by Brock Allen.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Base64Url encoder/decoder
    /// </summary>
    public static class Base64Url
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Encodes the specified byte array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arg">The argument.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Encode(byte[] arg)
        {
            var s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg); // Standard base64 encoder
            
            s = s.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
            s = s.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
            s = s.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
            
            return s;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decodes the specified string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arg">The argument.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Illegal base64url string!</exception>
        public static byte[] Decode(string arg)
        {
            var s = arg;
            s = s.Replace('-', '+'); // 62nd char of encoding
            s = s.Replace('_', '/'); // 63rd char of encoding
            
            switch (s.Length % 4) // Pad with trailing '='s
            {
                case 0: break; // No pad chars in this case
                case 2: s += "=="; break; // Two pad chars
                case 3: s += "="; break; // One pad char
                default: throw new Exception("Illegal base64url string!");
            }
            
            return Convert.FromBase64String(s); // Standard base64 decoder
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or [WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urlencode) (.Net Core 1.0+)