# how to add a jwt token to the url?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, change-password

I want to allow users to reset their password. In order to do so, I first check if their email exists in the database, if so, I send them an email with a link to a reset-password page. In order to make sure the link is secure, the latter is made with a jwt token that is only valid for 15mn.

However, the url cannot be reached because there are "." in the jwt:

`http://www.myapp.com/reset-password/eyJhbGciOInR5cC.ICJlywY2svp6eL98LHd.RpYylmPI`

If I remove the dots, the url is understood (I use React router by the way). How to fix this? Is there another way to achieve this reset formula with a temporary url?

Comment: `.` is not invalid nor does it need encoding with encodeURIComponent etc, your need to fix how you handle that incoming route parameter as thats where the issue is. btw a jwt seems excessive when you can make a small hash and store in db with a date

Comment: Just now tried to catch string with dots, and express successfully catches it.
Can you provide more info?
Used express@4.17.1

`app.get('/reset/:pass', (req, res) => { /* decrypt here, and continue */ res.send(req.params.pass)})`

Comment: @DenisRohlinsky I use React and react-router. It's a single page application, the pages are not served by a server. The server is only here to handle db transactions. My route is defined as such:<Route path="/reset-password/:token"component={ResetPassword}/>. It crashes if the token contains ".".

Comment: @LawrenceCherone What would be your strategy with the hash in the db?

Comment: You can replace the periods with `%2E` or append a trailing slash to the URL: `https://www.example.com/your.JWT/` rather than `https://www.example.com/your.JWT`. See [How to encode periods for URLs in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938900/how-to-encode-periods-for-urls-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
Buffer.from(token).toString('base64url')
```

then decode by

```
Buffer.from(urlParam, 'base64url').toString()
```

or on frontend by

```
const base64 = urlParam.replaceAll('_', '/').replaceAll('-', '+');
jwtToken = window.atob(base64),
```

you can read more about base64url there https://stackoverflow.com/a/55389212/6398044

Answer (score -2):

Instead of sending JWT token as GET param, send your JWT token through `Authorization: Bearer` which **I would recommend to do** (For more details see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

If you use Axios for your requests, then you can check out answer right over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988238/sending-the-bearer-token-with-axios)

As an example of headers you can [find here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/verifying-bearer-tokens)