# Jwt Flutter Authentication flow

Tags: flutter, dart, jwt, bloc

I am trying to create a Flutter application with Jwt token authentication.
I have referred [this article](https://dev.to/carminezacc/user-authentication-jwt-authorization-with-flutter-and-node-176l) as a starting point. But I want to refresh the tokens on like 15 minutes. So I don't think this article makes sense and also I want to add state management to this as well. I was thinking about Bloc or provider.
Some help with implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the token in your local storage and use [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) to check the token expiration date (timestamp) after decoding it with this [simple snippet code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017389/how-to-get-the-claims-from-a-jwt-in-my-flutter-application). If time the token is expired the call refresh_token api url